# Laravel query data according to pivot table relation

Tags: laravel

I have articles table, articles_categories table, and a pivot table between them with article_id and category_id columns, if I have the category_id how can I make query to return the articles related to this category?

the articles model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'img', 'content'];

    public function article_categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ArticleCategory::class);
    }
}
```

the categories model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ArticleCategory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function articles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have Models and Relationships defined? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69741561/edit) and include some relevant code, and any attempts you've made to solve this issue. If you haven't tried anything, that's a good place to start 

Comment: you can use methods like `wherePivot()`. More context https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#filtering-queries-via-intermediate-table-columns